# Markov chain and martingale: Taking one step to the right or going back to zero

Tags: probability, markov-chains, martingales

> Consider the Markov chain on nonnegative integers that does the
>   following: from any site $x \geq 0$ it jumps to $x + 1$ with
>   probability $p$ and to 0 with probability $1 − p$. Is this chain
>   transient? Null recurrent? Positive recurrent? You need to prove
>   whatever you claim.

Let $S_0=x$ and $S_n=x+X_1+X_2+\dots +X_n$.
$S_n$ is recurrent if $$P(\exists n\geq 1~|~ S_n=0)=1.$$ Furthermore, if the first return time is finite then we have positive recurrence and if it is infinite then we have null recurrence.

I believe that this depends on $p$. 
I am interested in $$P(\text{return to x} ~|~ \text{started at x})$$
I am having a hard time determining what I should do next and I was hoping for a bit of help.

I want to try and use a martingale. I am wondering if I need to know the mean and the variance of the Markov chain? I am not really sure how to find either of these.

Thank you for any help you can give to assist me.

Comment: It _ought to be_ clear that the chain is irreducible and recurrent. As to positive or null recurrent, consider finding the expect value to its return to zero using "first step" analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to use martingales in this instance but here is one way:

For any $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},$ we have $P^{(j+1)}_{i,j}   \geq  P_{i,0} \cdot P_{0,1} \cdot P_{1,2} \cdots P_{j-1,j} =  (1-p)p^j > 0$. Similarly, $P^{(i+1)}_{j,i}>0$. Then all states $i,j$ communicate and so the MC is irreducible.

Next, note that $P^{(n)}_{0,0} = (1-p)\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} {n-1 \choose k}p^{n-1-k}(1-p)^k = (1-p)(1)^{n-1}=(1-p).$ Therefore,$\ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P^{(n)}_{0,0} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (1-p) = \infty$ and so the MC is recurrent.

Finally, let $T_i$ be the waiting time for state $i$ and note that $P(T_0=k\ | \ X_0=0)=p^{k-1}(1-p).$ Then it follows that $E[T_0 \ | \ X=0] = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}kp^{k-1}(1-p)=\frac{1-p}{p} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}kp^k= \frac{1}{1-p}< \infty.$ So the MC is positive recurrent.

Comment: Thank you very  much. This is really great. I am going to go through this and make sure I understand it all.

Comment: NineteenNinetyNine is the notation $P_{i,j}^{(j+1)}$ the probability to go from i to j? What is the j+1 though? Sorry I am new to probability.

Comment: $P^{(j+1)}_{i,j}$ is the probability to go from $i$ to $j$ in $j+1$ steps.

Comment: Oh thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry one more question... Why does $\ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P^{(n)}_{0,0} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (1-p) = \infty$ give recurrence? I thought that we needed to show the probability $P_{0,0}$ was 1 to prove recurrence.

Comment: No problem. There is actually a theorem that says that a state $i$ is recurrent if $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P^{(n)}_{0,0}= \infty$. Also, $P_{0,0} = 1 \Rightarrow i$ is recurrent, but  $P_{0,0} < 1 \not \Rightarrow i$ is not recurrent.

Comment: Oh perfect. Thank you very much. I really want to understand this. I really appreciate your time :)